# Regex match first two occurrences of a capital letter followed by several lower case

Tags: c#, regex

I've been looking through the examples on here for how to do similar regex matches, but I can't get it to work for my situation.

I have a string like `ThisisMystringItsTooLong` and I want to get back `ThiMys` (**the first two occurrences of a capital letter followed by the two lower case letters after it**)
But, if the string there is simply `Thisismystring` (only one capital letter) then I just want
back `Thi`.

I've tried `([A-Z]{1})([a-z]{2}){0,1}` to get just the first occurrence of my match, in the case that there is more than 2 capital letters, but I'm not sure how to apply the second condition.

Comment: Can't you just concatenate the first and second matches? Otherwise, you can't really skip characters with a regex.

Comment: @MattBurland Yea I guess I could go that route, I don't use regex too often so I was curious if multiple scenarios could be handled in the way I mentioned. Good alternative though. Not sure what you meant by skipping characters, I'm more trying to do something along the lines of substring

Comment: @JWiley, I've created a function for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply use the Regex pattern `[A-Z][a-z]{2}` and do the other logic "manually".

```
public string ShortIdentifier(string longIdentifier)
{
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(longIdentifier, "[A-Z][a-z]{2}");
    if (matches.Count == 1) {
        return matches[0].Value;
    } else if (matches.Count >= 2) {
        return matches[0].Value + matches[1].Value;
    }
    return longIdentifier.Substring(0, Math.Min(longIdentifier.Length, 6));
    // Or return whatever you want when there is no match.
}
```

Change the Regex to `[A-Z][a-z]{1,2}` if you want to return one upper case letter followed by one or two lower case letters.

Comment: I'm trying to implement your solution, but I'm seeing it skip a match like `HelloThisIsString1`. The regex is only looking for one capital letter followed by exactly 2 lowercase. I want the match returned of `HelThi`, but this method will return `HelloTh` instead.

Comment: You must have a typo somewhere. I am getting `"HelThi"`. The first match will be `"Hel"` and the second `"Thi"` and there will also be a third unused one `"Str"`.

Comment: Ah, yes I added something in to account for words with only one following lowercase letter, with `{1,2}`, which seems to be forcing it to match that exact length. Is there a way to check for any number, but only return the first 2?

Comment: `[A-Z][a-z]{1,2}` should work. It will match as many lower case letters as possible but at most two, even if the word is longer. (Tested). For "HiThere" it will return "HiThe" and for "JonnyIsHere" it will return "JonIs".

Answer (score 3):

You can not do this with regular expressions only because a match is always continuous substring of the input. You can of course combine several matches to one end result.

```
String.Join(String.Empty, Regex.Matches(input, "[A-Z][a-z]{2}")
                               .Cast<Match>()
                               .Take(2)
                               .Select(match => match.Value));
```

Comment: Could you explain how the latter part is working for the second Join param?

Comment: It just gets all the matches for `[A-Z][a-z]{2}`, does a cast of the resulting match collection for technical reasons (`MatchCollection` implements only `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<Match>`), takes at most the first two matches, gets the matched text for each them and finally concatenates them by joining them with an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a method like this:

```
public string GetMyCharacters(string s)
        {
            int numOfCaps = Regex.Matches(s, "[A-Z]").Count;
            if (numOfCaps > 2)
            {
                var matches = Regex.Matches(s, "[A-Z][a-z]{2}");
                return matches[0].Value + matches[1].Value;
            }
            else if (numOfCaps == 1)
            {
                var matches = Regex.Matches(s, "[A-Z][a-z]{2}");
                return matches[0].Value;
            }
            else { return null; }
        }
```

Then call it like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(GetMyCharacters("ThisisMystringItsTooLong")); // ThiMys
Console.WriteLine(GetMyCharacters("Thisismystring")); // Thi
Console.WriteLine(GetMyCharacters("wijfowro"));// null
```

Answer (score 1):

I initially misunderstood the requirements, but here is the fixed version:

```
Regex.Replace(
    "ThisisMystringItsTooLong",
    "^(?:.*?([A-Z][a-z]{2}))?(?:.*?([A-Z][a-z]{2}))?.*$",
    "$1$2"
)
```

It matches the whole input string, start (^) to end ($) which it splits into:

```
(?:.*?([A-Z][a-z]{2}))? - optional non-capturing group, which consists of
                          a bunch of non-greedy anything followed
                          by substring sought, which is captured
(?:.*?([A-Z][a-z]{2}))? - another exactly same group; if we want to place
                          some limits on what can be between substrings
                          sought (like no spaces etc.) it goes here
                          instead of the anything
?.*                     - anything else
```

Then it constructs output string by concatenating two (possibly empty) matches by using Regex.Replace method. Tested with:

```
"ThisisMystringItsTooLong" -> "ThiMys"
"Thisismystring"           -> "Thi"
"thisismystring"           -> ""
"that is His String"       -> "HisStr"
"oh Hi There!"             -> "The"
"oh Hi There Go Here"      -> "TheHer"
```

Differs from Danies's answer by not using anything except the regex, but not sure if it performs better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

Try http://regex101.com/r/pU4aB5 which is

```
([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2})[a-z]*([A-Z]{1}[a-z]{2})?
```

And then what you'll need is to concatenate both capture groups to get your final result.